# Publishing CSS styles to geoserver in Java is not an SLD

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, style-manager

I want to directly upload and publish a CSS format style in Java, but after trying for a while, it has failed.I don't want to manually convert it to SLD format. Has anyone done anything similar or know a solution?